# Re : Saving downloaded Files into MyDocuments

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a doubt from  a silverlight application we can access MyDocuments. I am creating an Application which will download a set of files from a remote server . Is it possible to save these file in MyDocuments instead of Isolated Storage. I am using Silverlight 4.0 . Can any one give me Sample codes for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to acheive that you need to use Silverlight 4 and specify that is should get elevated privileges when install as an Out-of-browser application.  When running as an OOB the app will have access to the users Documents folder.

In all other cases you will need to use the `SaveFileDialog` where the user can explictly specify where to save the file.

**Edit** code example:-

```
if (Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions)
{
   string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
   path = Combine.Path(path, "MySaveFile.dat");
   using (var filestream = File.OpenWrite(path))
   {
        // pump your input stream in to the filestream using standard Stream methods
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using Silverlight 4.0 can you  give me sample code for it

Answer (score 0):

No Isolated storage is currently the only option.